# Scala snippet to TypeScript (how to convert abstract type members)

Tags: typescript, scala, type-level-computation

I have a small snippet of value level and type level list in Scala

```
sealed trait RowSet {
  type Append[That <: RowSet] <: RowSet

  def with[That <: RowSet](that: That): Append[That]
}

object RowSet {

  case object Empty extends RowSet {
    type Append[That <: RowSet] = That

    override def with[That <: RowSet](that: That): Append[That] = that
  }

  case class Cons[A, B <: RowSet](head: A, tail: B) extends RowSet { self =>
    type Append[That <: RowSet] = Cons[A, tail.Append[That]]

    override def with[That <: RowSet](that: That): Append[That] = Cons(head, tail ++ that)
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to convert this thing to TypeScript. As we don't have the [Abstract Type Members](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html) feature, I cannot seem to find a solution which doesn't require to type cast at some point.

What I currently have in TypeScript (also available on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSgewO4GUBTRAbwCgFKFRIZ4FcBLCACwB4AVF4RQgDwiEAdgBMMOAsQB8AClY8AXAi48AlEolEIZAL5kyEAJ4AHQggCCx06M4tGGfoNHi8WgDTLuvAcLFZX0ggAvBRUXPYIjr4YAMLYQmBsjEIAZoRQFh7JaRkAQlIIAPwIcQls5h6W1iJsuR4qEFIFSg0A3PooaBgAogC2xkaRPs7%20kqShlMYAriDIjLAMzOwNQ05%20mtJyXi1e6p48CORUxwhQxFNQQgjyEO3Henpknegl8YkVCLmr0aNaBVEjDbjY6wN7QKbwbBQGTTWbzU6EYAieLIQwIFiIkRKD6wuYLM5IlFoiDARjIJS5VSHCYnMBTUzQ1R3KiPY64%20FMVi2A4A9YBRpbRT7CB7UrvSpWXy1epeJrUk5UM4QC5XISEXCvBJbewAOgxSI8rF1JLJOs5LEFIuoGCqUrqwqkqhpDw6YIQfGCCDVGrFMgArB5vQg%20gNDE7QQlEGigl71ZqwDIAER2ROBuMhozht0AL09fDNSxkYaAA))

```
abstract class RowSet {
    abstract with<That extends RowSet>(that: That): RowSet
}

type Append<This extends RowSet, That extends RowSet> =
    This extends Cons<infer A, infer B> ? Cons<A, Append<B, That>> : That;

class Empty extends RowSet {
    public with<That extends RowSet>(that: That): That {
        return that;
    }
}

class Cons<A, B extends RowSet> extends RowSet {
    constructor(public readonly head: A, public readonly tail: B) {
        super();
    }

    public with<That extends RowSet>(that: That): Cons<A, Append<B, That>> {
        return new Cons(this.head, this.tail.with(that) as Append<B, That>)
    }
}

const x = new Cons(5, new Empty)    // Cons<number, Empty>
const y = new Cons("hi", new Empty) // Cons<string, Empty>
const z = x.with(y)                 // Cons<number, Cons<string, Empty>>
```

What I'm interested in is if we can avoid casting here:

```
return new Cons(this.head, this.tail.with(that) as Append<B, That>)
```

It seems that TypeScript understands that the value is actually `Append<B, That>` as it doesn't allow to cast to anything different, e.g. `Append<B, B>` or something similar. But because we use `with` from `abtract class RowSet` we end up with `Cons<A, RowSet>`.

Can we define RowSet differently, so that TypeScript correctly infers everything without our help? Maybe there is a different way of conversion of abstract type members (when converting from Scala)?

Comment: The problem is in type `Append`. TS does not play well with conditional types in ReturnType place. Most of the time, TS should infer  your type and you should not explicitly define return type. If you remove Append type from your code, it will work. I assume you want to implement some sort of linked list. Am I correct?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yeah, a linked list which holds information about all the values on type level. I tried removing the `Append` type, but the problem remains in `Cons` where my return type is going to be `Cons<A, That>` and it says that `Type 'Cons<A, RowSet>' is not assignable to type 'Cons<A, That>'`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2uowes0AL0tfF1Sxk7qAA

Comment: Take a look, it works without Append

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thank you, you are indeed correct, that it can work without the `Append`. Unfortunately, the thing I'm after is actually keeping the list of types in my list. Without `Append` the `z` variable becomes simply `Cons<number, RowSet>` losing all the information about other values (and I intend to use that information later)

Comment: Please have a look https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFEC2kIBkCWA7A1tAJhgM6iwC8sA3sLDbABbQCGeAXLJgK4A2XwAvmChwMOfEVAAeACoA+MpWq0GzNlIA0imqEboubEbgLpi0uQB923XvxABjAPaZisB0-nS1sVPINjjk2RkACgA6MMYAJwBzQjYAbWVWSx5PbV02Th4AXVgLBKYk9Vg0vS8sgEoyOSpaF0dnfOZUnS4c8kiYzVgI6FAOCMxKegLm3VgBAWBXZx7CbhJyaaCAJk8lgEY1+qDMrk9d8sOAbin6kkT5WfmQi4B6W9hl3OTeaZISy+g5rlAQj-uhokWJtii02GEQuM7Gd2NAAB6gAASBXkJQA-DcUQD1qcnCRMPDQFIWqiWhj-g9GDwXgByQjAIA 
I prepeared a simple implementation of linked list

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this implementation more (the first thing that bothers me right away is that even though we know our head is `2` the type of `head` variable is `2 | null`)

Comment: You can try F-bounded polymorphism to refer to own type, e.g. `class RowSet<T extends RowSet<T>>`. That would force you to use `Append<T, That>` as a signature in base class, but you won't have to cast. No playground link because it doesn't fit lol.

Comment: Thank you @OlegPyzhcov. It does indeed work with F-bounded polymorphism in this case. Marked it as solved. Once again thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Oleg Pyzhcov's comment I was able to make it work without any manual type casting. F-bounded polymorphism was suggested as a way to tackle this problem, and it turns out that it does help here

The solution looks like this, no type casting is needed, everything works as expected

```
abstract class RowSet<T extends RowSet<T>> {
    abstract with<That extends RowSet<That>>(that: That): Append<T, That>
}

type Append<This extends RowSet<This>, That extends RowSet<That>> =
    This extends Cons<infer A, infer B> ? Cons<A, Append<B, That>> : That;

class Empty extends RowSet<Empty> {
    public with<That extends RowSet<That>>(that: That): That {
        return that;
    }
}

class Cons<A, B extends RowSet<B>> extends RowSet<Cons<A,B>> {
    constructor(public readonly head: A, public readonly tail: B) {
        super();
    }

    public with<That extends RowSet<That>>(that: That): Cons<A, Append<B, That>> {
        return new Cons(this.head, this.tail.with(that))
    }
}

const x = new Cons(5, new Empty)    // Cons<number, Empty>
const y = new Cons("hi", new Empty) // Cons<string, Empty>
const z = x.with(y)                 // Cons<number, Cons<string, Empty>>
```

You can check it on [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=74#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSgewO4GUBTCAHgBUFCAPCQgOwBMMcDjyA%20dhAbwCgEBCUJBjwEuAJYQAFuWnBE1Wo2Z4ipMvIicAFDIUAuBJoUBKIwEEADlfoNyAGmNb2vAL69eEAJ62E120Y5CQwlO1VWDWkQ9icTRRpwrDU2eM4EAF5%20QU0QykSVBABhbDowEgk6ADNCKH8nSpq6gCEuAH5i0vKLJwC7Ema4ly4jeIBuTxQ0DABRAFsrH3zlJmTIknnF7y4%20QQQrAFcQZAlYcSlZeOWklnU5BV19CFGtc2cFHmy9gShiA6g6AgnhM9h4PLwpuhOmUSD0EM1roVbmxWlwwkiUqQSjCeqjPntYF1oAd4NgoDpDsdTghfsAGKVkN4ENJCHTLE5KSczrT6XRGUDgBJkEZmqZ8d8BGADrZyaYQYJwXtOdTJDJ7gkVhE7ml2HotC8zEZsd1ejZ%20oN3todl9vr8IP9AXRCLhoWA9SEAHQsulOGSeiCC5Ae1XSPVmUw2sGTIkIKiZBBOl3GnQAViciYQmx8YsEAHpc66SHQDnMQLUnFnthCY0yMgnna6dAAiaJN9MNyti-OFkSVADmFYWPlchLKiAAXvGqMGLjpvDmJYuBN3jUWS2WoE5V726APM0PtlwgA)

Comment: This is clever solution! Can I use this solution in my TS blog?

Comment: That is probably the best it can get - it effectively rewrites `this.Append[That]` to `Append<this, That>` trough extra type parameter. Glad to know it worked for you :)

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov, can I use it in my blog?

Comment: @captain-yossarian of course you can, it is an open question, we are not hiding here anything :)

Comment: Yeah, godspeed :) Hope you can get something interesting out of it