# TypeScript: TS2352: 'Type' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TreeNode<Type>'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
abstract class TreeNode<Type extends TreeNode<Type>> {
    children: Type[];

    protected constructor() {
        this.children = [];
    }
    
    addSelfToParent(parent: Type) {
        parent.children.push(this as Type);
    }

    // ...
}
```

typescript compiler emits the following error on the `this as Type` part.

```
TS2352: Conversion of type 'this' to type 'Type' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Type', but 'Type' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TreeNode<Type>'.
    Type 'TreeNode<Type>' is not comparable to type 'Type'.
      'Type' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TreeNode<Type>'.
```

When I replace the part with `this as unknown as Type`, the error goes away.

I'm particularly confused with the 'unrelated to' part in the error message.

**QUESTION**: How can it be an 'unrelated' type? `Type` is defined to be an extended type of `TreeNode<Type>`.

TypeScript version is 4.1.5.

**UPDATE 1**

Added the sample code to answer Linda Paiste' question.

First, original class code with some more example code (and `as` error fixed).

```js
   abstract class TreeNode<Type extends TreeNode<Type>> {
        children: Type[];

        protected constructor() {
            this.children = [];
        }

        addSelfToParent(parent: Type) {
            parent.children.push(this as unknown as Type);
        }

        // ...
    }

    class TreeNodeWithValue extends TreeNode<TreeNodeWithValue> {
        value: number;

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.value = 1;
        }
    }

    function sumValuesOfChildren(node: TreeNodeWithValue) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++)
            sum += getChildValue(node.children[i]);
        console.log(sum);
    }

    function getChildValue(node: TreeNodeWithValue) {
        return node.value;
    }
```

Here, getChildValue() can be called without any typescript error.

But when 'extends ...' is removed as follows,

```js
    abstract class TreeNode<Type>
    {
        children: TreeNode<Type>[];

        protected constructor() {
            this.children = [];
        }

        addSelfToParent(parent: TreeNode<Type>) {
            parent.children.push(this);
        }
    }

    class TreeNodeWithValue extends TreeNode<TreeNodeWithValue> {
        value: number;

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.value = 1;
        }
    }

    function sumValuesOfChildren(node: TreeNodeWithValue) {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++)
            sum += getChildValue(node.children[i]);
        console.log(sum);
    }

    function getChildValue(node: TreeNodeWithValue) {
        return node.value;
    }
```

Typescript compiler emits the following error on `getChildValue(node.children[i])`.

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'TreeNode<TreeNodeWithValue>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TreeNodeWithValue'.
   Property 'value' is missing in type 'TreeNode<TreeNodeWithValue>' but required in type 'TreeNodeWithValue'
```

I can avoid the error by downcasting like this: `getChildValue(node.children[i]) as TreeNodeWithValue`.

But I don't want this downcasting. The downcasting effectively nullifies the point of generic itself. For this, I had to add (ugly) 'extends...'.

**UPDATE 2**

kaya3's suggestion mostly works, but it does not work if a method that handles the `children` property is added in the subclass, as follows:

```js
abstract class TreeNode {
    children: this[];

    protected constructor() {
        this.children = [];
    }

    addSelfToParent(parent: this) {
        parent.children.push(this);
    }
}

class TreeNodeWithValue extends TreeNode {
    value: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = 1;
    }

    addChild() {
        this.children.push(new TreeNodeWithValue());  // ERROR
    }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'TreeNodeWithValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this'.
  'TreeNodeWithValue' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TreeNodeWithValue'.
```

Comment: Is the `extends` really necessary?  You don't need any assertion at all with `abstract class TreeNode<Type> { children: TreeNode<Type>[];  addSelfToParent(parent: TreeNode<Type>) { parent.children.push(this); }  }`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks. I've added related example code and some explanation. Please see 'UPDATE' section.

Comment: Btw, you have a lot of mutations in your code. TS does not play well with them.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is that the children have the same type as the parent, so you should use [`this` as a polymorphic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) instead of having a generic type parameter:

```
abstract class TreeNode {
    children: this[];

    protected constructor() {
        this.children = [];
    }

    addSelfToParent(parent: this) {
        parent.children.push(this);
    }
}

class TreeNodeWithValue extends TreeNode {
    value: number;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.value = 1;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKlApjgcgPYAmOCA3gLABQCdSAFgJbLG4B2AXAhM2ANoBdANw0a9BAAcohCDng5iSQu0hQArvEJQAFAEoK4ifV5MwAOljNWHBAF4EQ0bXoBfMS7rBixAMo5kADNMQgAFYA4IHUkInHYIblMwAypPYxjIy2s2OPNJdTAGHSS9Zwl3agqaFDQMbDwiUgB1Jl4ANWBkdTIcAA85dmI63AISMlSJADdO7u52dQBbEBwoZyM6WBU1TQhtfUM0iTB1SRX9MuM6JPNprrIHAEYLugqq6kD1dngmFQRjhY6dzAAHlAgBhbIcHTsMbceqjZqtBiA7opdYIZA4RD-ewIAAMzwQgW0CB0mMQTFxBIQlIAPAgYaQsiwcuxzJj2ABzXjCGkAaj5enRR0WCD5Dk5WIhLJROGhY2ZNji-CYglK6M2qkImPZhE5On+6sqHg+XwgP3YCElEGlrFl8tIcJGjRwLXaMxwaLSuAg6iglsZOBuHucFSAA)

Your generic type doesn't quite work because `Type extends TreeNode<Type>` doesn't necessarily mean that `Type` *equals* `TreeNode<Type>`. So `this` has type `TreeNode<Type>`, you want to use it where `Type` is expected, but the former is a supertype of the latter so it isn't assignable without a type assertion. On the other hand if you change the type of `children` to be `TreeNode<Type>[]`, then when you get a child from the array, it's a supertype of `Type`, so you can't use it how you want.

Comment: Thanks. Using polymorphic type looks cleaner than the generic + casting. BTW, regarding the type relation, I too wish that Type is a subtype of TreeNode<Type>. But typescript compiler says otherwise. It says in the error message that Type and TreeNode<Type> can be 'unrelated'. So 'hard' casting - this as unknown as Type must be used, instead of 'normal' downcasting - this as Type. I want to know the reason. How can they be unrelated types?

Comment: They can't be unrelated, since `Type` is declared as extending `TreeNode<Type>` so it must be a subtype. Typescript is just giving a misleading error message.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and it mostly works, but it breaks after a method is added in the subclass. please see my UPDATE 2 in the question.

Comment: Your updated code fails because if you write a subclass of `TreeNodeWithValue`, then its `children` array must contain only instances of that subclass, but your code would add an instance of `TreeNodeWithValue` to this array even for a subclass. This is a logical problem with your added method; you could write `let cls = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);` and then use `new cls(this)` to construct a child of the correct class, but beware that in that case every class in your hierarchy needs to have a constructor with that signature. Alternatively, abandon inheritance and use composition instead.

Comment: By the way, it is not good to substantially change the question's requirements after you have received an answer to what the question originally was. This invalidates existing answers, and makes your Q&A less useful to people searching for the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question. BTW actually my question was not regarding how to workaround the problem (albeit somewhat unclear - so I updated the 'QUESTION' part). My real question was answered by your comment above, that is - 'it is a bug of TypeScript compiler'. Anyway I think that the workaround is practically useful, so I'm somewhat trying to 'upgrading' the workaround. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a bug in the compiler, and I did not say it is. Your code is not type-safe, and the compiler reports a type error, which is the correct behaviour. The issue with the compiler is only that the error message could be made more accurate. My answer is not a "workaround" for a compiler bug.

Comment: First, the message is misleading, and that's a kind of bug. And more, it's not only message. If the compiler behaves correctly, this as Type should suffice. But the compiler insists this is unknown as Type. That's incorrect if the two types are related. For 'workaround' word, I meant 'another coding method that avoids the problem in the first place.'

Answer (score 1):

In TS you can explicitly type `this`

Example:

```js
abstract class TreeNode<Type extends TreeNode<Type>> {
  children: Type[];

  protected constructor() {
    this.children = [];
  }
  // special syntax of typing THIS
  addSelfToParent(this: Type, parent:Type) {
    parent.children.push(this); // ok
  }

}
```

As you see - no type assertions.

Btw, you can find [this article](https://catchts.com/linked-list) or[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849973/scala-snippet-to-typescript-how-to-convert-abstract-type-members) interesting.

Comment: Thanks, but it makes the other methods in the class (though not present in the example code) cannot call the method (without some casting).  
Typescript emits the following error --

TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'this' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Type'.   'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Type', but 'Type' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TreeNode<Type>'.     Type 'TreeNode<Type>' is not assignable to type 'Type'.       'Type' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TreeNode<Type>'.

Comment: No problem, have you published whole part of code?

Comment: The code in the question is artificial one to reproduce the (strange) error with minimal amount of code. In the real code, the class has several other methods.